# Sorting Dates in R in an unusual format

Tags: r, date, datetime, datetime-format

I figured there must be a package or technique I do not know of to handle this.  I have dates in a file saved as strings in the following format

```
Wed Jan 20 07:59:28 +0000 2016
```

I was curious, does R have some sort of package that would convert this to a date-object that can then be sorted?  I know there exists date formats, but none that match this one.

Comment: See https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html There is an example near the end of the page that is very close to what you have.

Comment: Thanks! I had considered that package, but it is not available for 3.2.3.  Is my only real option to downgrade my version?

Thanks again.

Comment: Ignore that, I never included base -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lubridate` and `chron` are great, but all you really need here is base's `strptime`:

```
strptime('Wed Jan 20 07:59:28 +0000 2016', '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y')
# [1] "2016-01-20 02:59:28"
```

Note that it converts the time zone from what's supplied to the local by default, so if you want UTC, use

```
strptime('Wed Jan 20 07:59:28 +0000 2016', '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y', tz = 'UTC')
# [1] "2016-01-20 07:59:28 UTC"
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Now to convert several million dates so I can sort them... gonna be a long wait I feel.